# Ubuntu terminal shortcuts not working (and no menu bar)

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I am new to Ubuntu(20.04.1). I just want to open a second tab of terminal.

The Ubuntu terminal shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> does not work. In fact none of the terminal shortcuts work. Also there is no menu bar on the terminal. Lots of blog posts say open settings, but I don't see a way to do that.

[Here is an image of what the terminal looks like when I open it [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcrSM.jpg)

Comment: Hey Milo Lynch! Can you please add a screenshot of the terminal such that we can have a better idea? (Use the [edit] feature to edit your question)

Answer (score 0):

For gnome-terminal:

Go to **prefrences > shortcuts**

[image: menu in gnome-terminal]

Mark the checkbox **enable shortcuts**. Make sure the **New Tab** action has the shortcut key that you want to use.

[image: shortcuts setting]

Comment: Where is preferences > shortcuts. The terminal has no menu bar and the Ubuntu settings I get through my desktop only show app permissions and uninstall options

Comment: @MiloLynch , from image it looks like wsl not gnome-terminal on ubuntu. I'm not sure it's even possible to use tabs on wsl.

Comment: Oh thank you so much sorry for the confusion